# Ordering attributes / namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like know if there is an order defined in which attributes and namespace definitions can occur in an xml tag element. Let's assume the following element:

```
<tag attr1="a1" attr2="a2" xmlns="ThisIsTheNameSpace">value</tag>
```

So the question is: Must be the xmlns after the attributes or before them or doesn't it matter.

```
<tag xmlns="ThisIsTheNameSpace" attr1="a1" attr2="a2">value</tag>
```

or could it be anywhere like this:

```
<tag attr1="a1" xmlns="ThisIsTheNameSpace" attr2="a2">value</tag>
```

Are there any kind of definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section 3.1 of the Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition), no, the order does not matter.

```
Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element
tag is not significant.
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

Comment: Hm. May be i misunderstand a thing but in this http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-using it is mentioned that the xmlns has to be the first one?

Comment: I don't see any reference to the attribute order in that article. It makes refernece to a namespace prefix having to be in the start tag or an ancestor tag but that's all I see that could be related to this. That's not a reference to attribute order though.

Comment: Outch you are right. I oversight that the grammer defines a logical or between NSAttName and QName etc. So no order definition. You are correct. Thanks.